# if global b>global a: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

i'm getting a SyntaxError on line 8 of the code below.

```
import random
import sys
a=random.randint(1, 30)
b=random.randint(1, 30)
c= "minus" or "plus"
print(c)
def f():
    if global b>global a:
      a=random.randint(1, 30)
      b=random.randint(1, 30)
    print(a+b)
```

Comment: `c = "minus" or "plus"` does exactly the same thing as `c = "minus"`. I'm not sure what you think the `or "plus"` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to discuss in great length the unnecessary use of global variables here (it would be better to pass a/b as parameters).

The syntax you used (`if global b>global a:`) is invalid. The `global x` is a definition of the scope of a variable, it is done once and should be on its own line.

The correct syntax should be:

```
import random
import sys
a=random.randint(1, 30)
b=random.randint(1, 30)
c= "minus" or "plus"             ## not sure what this is doing
print(c)
def f():
    global a                     ## definition of global scope
    global b
    if b>a:                      ## use of variables
      a=random.randint(1, 30)
      b=random.randint(1, 30)
    print(a+b)
```

and presumably you want to call `f` at some point:

```
f()
```

Comment: that totally fixed it, thank you! the code is a bit messy, as i am new to coding, and it is a bit of a much longer program.